# What do you think if I use JAX-RS to implement Web Apps (vs Web Services)?

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs, restful-url, restful-architecture

I like the way JAX-RS represent URLs.. and find it very easy to be used.

I am thinking of making the JAX-RS works instead of my Servlets, so I can write some JSPs that interact directly with these RESTful resources ...

What do you think?

Comment: So you want to have _two_ JVM's?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Could be done within a single container easily enough.

Comment: @DonalFellows but _why_ would anyone do _that_?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a decision about your model programming, is a decision about architecture and requirements of your application.

Answer (score 0):

My first experience with JAX-RS was very positive. I used the framework to provide some server side functionality to a desktop app.  But I wouldn't see the value of using REST if you are creating a traditional Web app where each client action results in a new Web page getting loaded by the user's browser.  If you are building an AJAX app, then I can see how REST might be cleaner to code than Servlet.

What is the nature of the project?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't matter servlets or even use PHP/HTML front end as you JAX-RS use HTTP request. I would suggest you to use JAX-RS reference implementation for building RESTful Web services call [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/). It provide more goodies ..